# How do I format the match() parameter to locate a string in email?

Tags: javascript

I found the following Google Script which appears to do what I want. It searches for emails in MyLabel, but instead of locating the string for "StoreID:" and returning the characters that appear after that string in my Google Sheets, it only returns the 'false' response of "No Store ID".

The code that needs refinement is:

```
  tmp = content.match(/Store ID:\n([\s\S]+)/);
  var StoreID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No Store ID';
```

But I cannot figure out how to improve it. Shall I use regexp or how can I get this content.match(); to work, please?

The body of the email looks like the following:

> Store ID: 123456
>   Manager Name: John Smith

I would like to extract and write to a Google Sheets both bits of data to look like the following:

> 123456      John Smith

The following is the full script - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtyrA.png

Comment: There is no `\n` after "Store ID:", so your expression doesn't match.

Comment: Also, `[\s\S]` is a useless character class as it matches all whitespace and non-whitespace characters. Might as well use `.`

Comment: Try `/Store ID: (\d+)/` (assuming the value is always numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex does not work given the string you have provided, as there is no newline character. Perhaps you can use `\s` to match any white space character instead.

You can try the following regex to capture both `StoreID` and `managerName`:

```
tmp = content.match(/Store ID:\s*(\d+)\s*Manager Name:\s*(.*)/);
var storeID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1]: 'No Store ID';
var managerName = (tmp && tmp[2]) ? tmp[2]: 'No manager name';
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fG6fX6/2)

If you happen to know that the manager name result always returns in the format of `Firstname LastName`, you can replace the `.*` with `\w*\s*\w*` to be a more specific match. This will prevent characters after manager name from being captured as part of the manager name itself.

**Edit:** If the content body contains multiple `StoreID` and `ManagerName`, then instead of the above, you can split up the matches into `StoreID` and `ManagerName` like so:

```
var storeMatches = content.match(/Store ID:\s*(\d+)/g);
var managerMatches = content.match(/Manager Name:\s*(\w*\s*\w*)/g);
```

But the above assumes that you don't have any empty values.

It may be better to split up the lines by newline and then match the above.

Comment: Need to be careful of anything following the manager name as this will also pick that up

Comment: @Phil I agree. Tim, please take note of the comment by Phil. If your string does not end with the manager name, the regex needs to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! So to account for the end of string, I tried the following which works. Please let me know if how the match() is better. 

    var label = "Manager Name:";
    var nextLabel = "Store ID:";
    var pos = content.search(label);
    var start = pos+label.length;
    var end = content.search(nextLabel); // End at the next field
    var distance = end - start; // end first so that result is not negative
    var ManagerName = content.substr(start,distance);

Comment: Can't figure out how to get my code to appear in this forum properly spaced

Comment: @TimSideris Does this mean you will have multiple `Store ID` and ManagerName` entries in one string? If so, you can split up the regex into matching `Store ID` only and `ManagerName` only, and just go down the list of matches where match 1 for `StoreID` would correspond with match 1 of `ManagerName`. If there is always two words for `ManagerName` then you can use the option at the end of my answer. You will also need the global tag. I'll edit my answer above with it. Your answer seems okay if it's just one line.

Comment: @timoLawl - Yes, that is a good point. In this instance, it is all one line, but regexp is best for multiple lines. Thank you!